# How can I password-protect AVI video files from a DVD?

Tags: dvd, passwords, privacy-protection

I have a DVD that contains five videos with a total file size of 3GB. I want to protect these files with password.

Compressing them into a password-protected ZIP file and manually extracting them for each use takes too long. How can I easily protect big video files with passwords but still open those files easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend that you store the files in an encrypted format.  With the file encrypted, no one would be able to access them without the encryption software and your encryption key (which you'd store on your computer or USB drive).  The encryption software could then decrypt the files on-the-fly.

I've never done this personally, but an online search found the [following tutorial](http://www.datacorpsonline.com/2011/how-to-store-encrypted-files-on-a-cd-or-dvd/) that sounds like it'll accomplish this.

Comment: The guide is for creating a [Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) volume, which sounds like the perfect solution here (also, Truecrypt is awesome).

Comment: I would suggest that you also include the Truecrypt stand alone executable on that DVD so it is easier for users to decrypt. Make sure you don't encrypt that as well :-)